# Create a lambda function in python3.5 that only take positive numbres

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I need to create a function that returns an exponencial function, but the exponential function only takes positive numbers, I tried using lambda (is part of the restrictions I have), and I tried this way:

```
def create(v):
    return (lambda x: (v*e**-(v*x)) if x>=0)
```

but it prompts Syntax error all the time:

```
File "<stdin>", line 8
  return (lambda x : (v*e**-(v*x)) if x>=0)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How could I make it work only with positive numbers?

Comment: What do you want it to do if the number entered is not positive?

Comment: A user (or caller) may provide negative values anyway. Ask yourself what part of the code is going to be executed if the input value to the function is negative.

Comment: I just want it to return None when the value provided is negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things wrong with your code:

1. You're missing the `else` clause, which is required when using the ternary operator. Python interpreter needs to know what to do if someone *does* enter a negative number.
2. While not *incorrect*, you don't need the outermost parameters around the whole `lambda` function.
3. Your parenthesis are placed incorrectly, the `if` should be one level deeper inside of the `lambda`'s body's parenthesis.

Now based on your comment:

> I just want it to return None when the value provided is negative

Here's what the final result should look like:

```
def create(v):
    return lambda x: (v*e**-(v*x) if x >= 0 else None)
```

As a matter of fact, you don't *need* the parenthesis around the `lambda`'s body either:

```
def create(v):
    return lambda x: v*e**-(v*x) if x >= 0 else None
```

Although at this point it might get complicated which operation is ran first, so I highly recommend keeping the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

A ternary expression always needs its `else` part, otherwise you haven't specified what should happen if the number is negative (which, although you desire it not happen, could still be the case).

For example:

```
>>> import math
>>> r = lambda x: math.sqrt(x) if x >= 0 else x
>>> r(9)
3.0
>>> r(-9)
-9
```

The syntax error you're getting is about the lack of that `else`.

Comment: I marked yours as the answer since is the most complete one, cheers mate!

Comment: @gramsch longer isn't always more complete, his answer doesn't include your original code and doesn't take into account your request of returning `None`. I'm not saying *his* anwer is invalid, I'm just saying *your* argument doesn't make much sense